# How do I make an HTML file on the servers with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Discord embed generator website. For this to work I made this:
[image]

I want this form to make a new HTML file and store all those inputs as a variable with Javascript. Absolute no PHP, Ruby, Node.js, Jquery or other stuff like that.

Comment: This is not possible because Javascript that is runing in the browser can not access your file system and so it can not create files.

Comment: Then you've to install node.js at your back-end. In all cases you will need some server-side code, browsers can't save anything into your server.

Comment: Can it work with Github pages?

Comment: Maybe it would if they have an API you can call via AJAX. You'd have to look it up

Comment: P.s. what's your objection to server-side code?

Comment: "GitHub pages host only static HTML pages. No server side technology is supported, so Node.js applications won't run on GitHub pages." so I am really forced to buy hosting and a domain for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Yes. This is what server side code does and what modern web frameworks are made for. Why don't you want to use back end though?

Comment: Cause it costs a lot of money and I can't afford.

Comment: HTML runs in the client so it can't modify the server. To do anything on the server, you need to run code on the server :) But PHP is free so if you find some free hosting somewhere it won't cost money...?

Comment: You could output the result on to the page just using dom manipulation in a textarea or something, the user can then copy and paste that html into whatever they want.

Comment: Free hosting is bad for the privacy like IPs, it makes the website down lots of times, and the domain then?

Comment: @Magrangs but I want this to not be only for programmers. I want people to press on that button and get a generated link what contains HTML in it to make the Discord embed work.

Comment: Then this is impossible without a backend. Also if you need to serve this via a url you will have to pay for hosting in any case?

Comment: That leaves me to one single choice. Waste money for hosting and a domain. That is the solution. Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: @crowdzer You could set up a node service using [zeit.co](https://zeit.co/) which is free.

Comment: Free hosting exists, but as you say it has drawbacks. You might also find you can use a cloud backend which won't cost you much, if anything, since you get a certain amount of traffic  for free - check out Azure Functions, for example. But you still have to host the HTML page somewhere, at least, even if the rest is auto-generated by the function. Or naybe you can think of a way to monetize your service to help pay for hosting, e.g. provide advertising, or charge people for using the service (e.g. using a freemium model..) depends if this is just some fun for your friends or a serious project.